# Weird: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, debugging, error-handling

> Note: I am not discussing the error here. I am wondering why I am having this error at this specific line.

I am getting this error on 3 different customers. I am not allowed to access their computers and data and I am not having this problem on my computer.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object......  vid
>   Windows.Page.UCAtgardSkuldsanering.
>   FillPdfSkuldFieldValues(Dictionary`2 fieldValues, Skuld skuld, Int32
>   SkuldNumber) i C:\Users\u706185\Source\Workspaces\Boss\Utveckling\1.
>   4.2\Windows\Page\UCAtgardSkuldsanering.cs:rad 1960 vid
>   Windows.Page.UCAtgardSkuldsanering.FillWithSkulder(Dictionary`2
>   fieldValues) i C:\Users\u706185\Source\Workspaces\Boss\Utveckling\1.
>   4.2\Windows\Page\UCAtgardSkuldsanering.cs:rad 1913 vid
>   Windows.Page.UCAtgardSkuldsanering.FillSkuldsaneringPdf()
>   i C:\Users\u706185\Source\Workspaces\Boss\Utveckling\1.
>   4.2\Windows\Page\UCAtgardSkuldsanering.cs:rad 1361 vid
>   Windows.MdiParent.letterToolStripButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) i
>   C:\Users\u706185\Source\Workspaces\Boss\Utveckling\1.
>   4.2\Windows\MdiParent.cs:rad 2792 vid System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)

The code at this location is:

[image]

```
    private void FillPdfSkuldFieldValues(Dictionary<string, string> fieldValues, Skuld skuld, int SkuldNumber)
    {
        if (skuld?.FordringsAgareNamn != null)
        {
            string s2 = (ApplicationHelper.FormatPostnummer(skuld.FordringsAgarePostnr) + " " + skuld.FordringsAgarePostOrt).Trim();
            string s1 = skuld.FordringsAgareAdress.Trim();
            fieldValues.Add($"BlankettFormular[0].SkuldsaneringPrivatperson[0].DinaSkulder[{ SkuldNumber }].Borgenar[0].NamnAdress[0]",
            string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new List<String> {
                skuld.FordringsAgareNamn,
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2) ?
                        s1 + ", " + s2 : (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) ? s1 : !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2) ? s2 : "")
            }.Where(sx => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sx))));

            fieldValues.Add($"BlankettFormular[0].SkuldsaneringPrivatperson[0].DinaSkulder[{ SkuldNumber }].Borgenar[0].Tfn[0]", skuld.FordringsAgareTelefon);
        }
```

FordringsAgareNamn property look like:

```
    public global::System.String FordringsAgareNamn
    {
        get
        {
            return _FordringsAgareNamn;
        }
        set
        {
            OnFordringsAgareNamnChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("FordringsAgareNamn");
            _FordringsAgareNamn = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true, "FordringsAgareNamn");
            ReportPropertyChanged("FordringsAgareNamn");
            OnFordringsAgareNamnChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _FordringsAgareNamn;
```

Skuld object is read from database and it should never been null. and FordringsAgareNamn is string. Why am I getting this error at this line 1960?

The project is Windows form application with .Net framework 4.6

> Note: I am not discussing the error here. I am wondering why I am having this error at this specific line.

Any help!!!!!

Comment: please post code as code

Comment: Did your customers run a debug version of your app? I guess it's a release version, so the stack trace may not be detailed enough...is it possible that the `FordringsAgareNamn` property getter (I guess it is a property) throws the exception and it just does not appear in the stack trace due to some kind of optimization?

Comment: Yes, FordringsAgareNamn is a property. The getter is just returning the value.
public global::System.String FordringsAgareNamn
        {
            get
            {
                return _FordringsAgareNamn;
            }
            set

Comment: If your question is why the exception is thrown at that particular line, then the answer is that your PDBs don't match your source code.

Comment: I have followed the stack trace and it does match the code at every line.

Comment: There's simply no way that `if (skuld?.FordringsAgareNamn != null)` can throw a `NullReferenceException` that I'm aware of, given the code you show. Unless in turn `_FordringsAgareNamn` is something other than a string field.

Comment: @CodeCaster. That is why I wrote Weird. I am not understanding what is happening here. Unfortunately _FordringsAgareNamn is a string.

Comment: I only ever heard of null conditional operator causing this kind of problem in cases like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33592547/891715  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218581/null-conditional-operator-not-behaving-as-expected-on-some-machines (related to await on tasks). Are you sure you don't have something in your project that uses this sort of thing under the hood? Could Skuld be some proxy type?

Comment: What do you mean by proxy type? Skuld is an item of an array which have been read from the database.

Comment: Do you have any `Equal`ity / `GetHash` overrides or custom operators defined?